# Can't run application/x-executable files in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (linaxepad)

Tags: executable

I'll hope that you can help me!!

I've tried to execute linaxepad (application/x-executable), extracting from "linaxepad.tar.gz" file.

But nothing happens (Ubuntu doesn't show anything) and if I try from terminal, Ubuntu shows this:

http://imageshack.com/a/img903/9783/zP7sbC.jpg

http://imageshack.com/a/img911/3939/E2IUny.jpg

My Ubuntu version is 14.04 LTS

I don't know if the .tar.gz file will be compatible.

The download section (Picaxe webpage) shows this:

"LinAXEpad for Linux (v1.5.0 for x386 with GTK2.8+)"

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when you run from terminal, the command is case sensitive. So run `LinAXEpad` with capital `L`.

LinAXEPad is not starting because some dependencies are missing. Here are the libraries needed (found using `ldd`):

```
    ldd LinAXEpad
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf777f000)
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 => not found
libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 => not found
libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => not found
libglib-2.0.so.0 => not found
libgthread-2.0.so.0 => not found
libgobject-2.0.so.0 => not found
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => not found
libpango-1.0.so.0 => not found
libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => not found
libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => not found
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf7740000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xf773b000)
libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0xf7729000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0xf7716000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0xf75e2000)
libstdc++.so.6 => not found
libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf759c000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf757e000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf73ce000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7780000)
libcairo.so.2 => not found
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0xf73ac000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0xf73a8000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xf73a0000)
```

It requires GTK 2. Note that if you have a 64 bit Ubuntu, 32 bit versions of those libraries will be required.

Try to install:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386 libcairo2:i386 libpango1.0-0:i386 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

Comment: Ok. With your code, I got this: "./LinAXEpad: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Comment: @Falconunknown `sudo apt-get install libstdc++6:i386`

Comment: Finally I could open LinAXEpad in Ubuntu. But terminal shows this (Don't know if that's right):          Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
(LinAXEpad:8674): Gtk-WARNING **: Imposible encontrar el motor de temas en la ruta al _modulo: «murrine»,
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

Comment: @Falconunknown that's ok. It's just telling you that the theme wasn't correctly loaded, bu that doesn't affect the functionality of the app.